# UIScrollView doesn't scroll - even with valid content size and scroll enabled

Tags: uiscrollview, autolayout

In my `viewDidAppear` method (in which i call to the super method) I have the following code:

```
UIScrollView *navbar = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];

[navbar setScrollEnabled:YES];
[navbar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[navbar setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

[self.view addSubview:navbar];

NSDictionary *viewsDictionary2 = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(navbar);

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[navbar]|"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:viewsDictionary2]];
 [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[navbar]|"
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:nil
                                                                     views:viewsDictionary2]];

NSArray *categories = @[@"nav1", @"nav2", @"nav3", @"nav4", @"nav5", @"nav6", @"nav7", @"nav8", @"nav9", @"nav10", @"nav11", @"nav12", @"nav13"];

NSMutableArray *tempCategoryImages = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < categories.count; i++)
{
    [tempCategoryImages insertObject:[UIImage imageNamed:categories[i]] atIndex:i];
}

NSArray *categoryImages = [tempCategoryImages copy];

//          Add subviews.
//
CGFloat xPadding = 25.0f;

UIView *previousImageView = NULL;

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < categoryImages.count; i++)
{
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:categoryImages[i]];

    [imageView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    [navbar addSubview:imageView];

    if (i == 0) {
        //
        //  First category.
        //
        [navbar addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                       toItem:imageView.superview
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                   multiplier:1
                                                                     constant:0]];
    } else {
        //
        //  End categories.
        //
        [navbar addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                       toItem:previousImageView
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                                   multiplier:1
                                                                     constant:xPadding]];
    }

    [navbar addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                   toItem:imageView.superview
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                               multiplier:1
                                                                 constant:0]];

    previousImageView = imageView;
}

//          Set content size.
//
CGSize scrollContentSize = CGSizeZero;

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < categories.count; i++)
{
    UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageNamed:categories[i]];

    //  Width.
    //
    scrollContentSize.width += tempImage.size.width;

    //  Height.
    //
    if (tempImage.size.height > scrollContentSize.height) {
        scrollContentSize.height = tempImage.size.height;
    }
}

navbar.contentSize = scrollContentSize;
```

Which when i log the scrollviews properties, it has the subviews, a large enough content size and scrolling enabled.

Even when I add the `UIScrollView` to IB and link it to the same code it then works? (I comment out the `NSAutoLayout` code.

This leads me to believe that for the UIScrollView to work, I cannot use Auto layout.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

***EDIT***

The code also doesn't work programatically, when I try `initWithFrame:`*frame* with `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES`

Comment: I haven't exactly found an answer, I've just rewritten my app so I use  IB instead of coding it in.

Comment: check the example linked in: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16029013/400544

Answer (score 0):

Check the attributes inspector for your scrollview in IB. Make sure that bounce vertically is checked.

Fixed this problem for me.