# Swift: is it correct to assign a custom class to all UINavigationControllers?

Tags: xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, autorotate

This is more or less my `Main.storyboard` situation:

[image]

where I have a root `UITabBarController` with 5 possibile choices. Then, I want that some `UIViewController`s can rotate to landscape while I want also some other `UIViewController`s to have only landscape mode. So I have written this file.swift:

```
class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

  override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    if (self.topViewController?.isKindOfClass(HomeViewController) != nil) {return false}
    else if (self.topViewController?.isKindOfClass(ServicesViewController) != nil) {return false}
    else if (self.topViewController?.isKindOfClass(PhotoGalleryViewController) != nil) {return false}
    else if (self.topViewController?.isKindOfClass(SelectMapViewController) != nil) {return false}
    else if (self.topViewController?.isKindOfClass(MapViewController) != nil) {return false}
    else {return true}
  }

}

class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
  override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return (self.selectedViewController as! UINavigationController).shouldAutorotate()
  }
}
```

and I have assigned to all `UINavigationController`s the same class 
`CustomNavigationController` while I have assigned `CustomTabBarController` class to `UITabBarController`. 
The result is that no view controller do not rotates. Is this because I have assigned the same class to them? Shall I create a custom navigation controller class for each `UINavigationController` I have?

**UPDATE**

A partial solution I found, even if it's a little intricate, is the following. I have modified the previous file like that:

```
class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return (self.topViewController?.shouldAutorotate())!
}

}
```

class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return (self.selectedViewController as! UINavigationController).shouldAutorotate()
    }
    }

Then, in view controllers where rotation is allowed I simply have:

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

while in view controllers where **rotation is not allowed** I have:

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
    UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
}
```

Anyway there's a little problem because the animation which sets mode to portrait is not correct meaning that the width of the screen is not adjusted. if I go from a landscape view controller to a portrait only view controller then the view controller frame is not correct. I get

[image]

instead of this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this in AppDelegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if let rootController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
        if let navigationController = rootController.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController {
            let controller = navigationController.topViewController!

            if controller.isKindOfClass(HomeViewController.classForCoder()) {
                return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
            }
            if controller.isKindOfClass(ServicesViewController.classForCoder()) {
                return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
            }
            if controller.isKindOfClass(PhotoGalleryViewController.classForCoder()) {
                return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
            }
            if controller.isKindOfClass(SelectMapViewController.classForCoder()) {
                return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
            }
            if controller.isKindOfClass(MapViewController.classForCoder()) {
                return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
            }
        }
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All
}
```

Update:

This method forces application to change orientation in ViewController that should be only in Portrait (HomeViewController, ServicesViewController, PhotoGalleryViewController, SelectMapViewController, MapViewController):

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
    UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I am afraid it does not work...they all rotate with no exception :(

Comment: @LoryLory sorry I have edited my answer. Previous worked only with Presented controller. This one should work. Also, it will work even without CustomNavigationController. Try it ;)

Comment: ok it works but now I have the problem described in my question update: if I go from a landscape view controller to a portrait only view controller then the view controller frame is not correct. Se the new images.

Comment: @LoryLory For that you need to add one more line of code in HomeViewController, ServicesViewController, PhotoGalleryViewController, SelectMapViewController, MapViewController. Check out answer

Comment: what you wrote is exactly the same code I added in my viewWillAppear() but the "transformation" is not right...I get that strage image as if the table view remains in landscape mode. I have tried to update its frame too but id does not change

Comment: it could be a auto layout bug as they say here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307037/bug-in-uitableview-layout-after-orientation-change

Comment: Try to play with attributes of View Controller where that table view is. Like "Should Adjust Scroll View Insets"

Comment: I have added `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true` to `viewWillAppear()` but neither this works :(

Comment: remove all func shouldAutorotate() methods, that's what prevents your controller from rotating back to Portrait. Leave only viewViwllAppear and main method in AppDelegate

Comment: sorry...nothing to do. I removed all `shouldAutorotate()` methods and custom class navigation controller and custom class tab bar controller. I just have `viewWillAppear()` like you wrote it... but it's useless. It looks so silly all this, it would be supposed to be such a simple thing...