# Is it necessary to update the TableView layout on rotation?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, rotation

When using a `collectionView` on the iPad and `rotating` it, I call:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

Is it necessary to do the same thing with a `tableView`?

I got the below code from this [older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14429025/4833705)

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need update layout when you rotation device. Because tableView will auto adjust cell layout when rotation.