# Xcode Scroll view being cut off when running simulation

Tags: ios, iphone, css, objective-c, controller

Here I have one view controller embedded in the navigation controller. In this view controller I have the navigation bar up top, with a undo button and a title. In the main content area I wanted to have two table views that can be scrolled through with X number of cells. I also wish to have one more button at the bottom. I haven't create the obj-c files for the controller or the objects yet but in the storyboard here's what I have:

[image]

And when I run it this is what happens:

[image]

Is this an auto-layout issue? I have no constraints set but I tried setting constraints and it didn't make a difference. I also tried just using 1 table and scroll view and still got some issues when I added the navigation bar. Any ideas?

I was reading this but was not sure if this solution applies to me: [UIScrollView is cut off from UITabBarController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265671/uiscrollview-is-cut-off-from-uitabbarcontroller)

Also, is the bottom navigation bar/tab appearing because I added a navigation item- Title, rather than just the navigation bar? I'm still new and learning and I'll still be looking for the answer while this is posted, but thanks for reading through this.

Comment: Do you have a github link to the project that I could mess with and try to fix since it looks like this is a pretty empty project?

Comment: Nope, i don't sadly sorry. Everything your looking at the pictures above is actually everything that has been done so far and is what I put together in around 5 minutes. I didn't think something like this would have an issue like this. If you wanna try and fix this on your screen I would say try implementing having two table views on one view controller with a navigation bar and seeing if your getting the same issue. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pin your `UIScrollView` to top and bottom of its parent view to make sure it sizes itself to the height of your phone screen.

Here are step by step instructions:
[Scroll View not functioning IOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20502860/scroll-view-not-functioning-ios-7/20503513#20503513)

Comment: Thanks for the step by step link, worked great. I actually didn't even use the scroll view but it helped me understand embedding views to parent views better.