# UIScrollview height change base on Uiwebview Contents

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview

Im trying to set height of `UIScrollView` base on my `UIWebView` Content.

Im using autolayout in story board and target are ios7.

i know how to hard code size into height of `UIScrollView` by this code :

```
-(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews{
     UIScrollView *sv = (UIScrollView *)[self.view viewWithTag:30];
    sv.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0,1200);
}
```

and also how to set `UIWebView` height base on contents :

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)bweb
{
    CGRect frame = byweb.frame;

    frame.size.height = 5.0f;

    bweb.frame = frame;
}
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

}
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)bweb{
    CGSize mWebViewTextSize = [bweb sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f)];
    CGRect mWebViewFrame = bweb.frame;
    mWebViewFrame.size.height = mWebViewTextSize.height;
    self.cellhieghtforwebview = &(mWebViewFrame.size.height);
    bweb.frame = mWebViewFrame;
    bweb.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    bweb.scrollView.bounces = NO;
    UIScrollView *sv = (UIScrollView *)[self.view viewWithTag:30];
    sv.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, *(self.cellhieghtforwebview));
    [self viewDidLayoutSubviews];
}
```

but dont know how to set the height of scrollview after setting the height of `UIWebView`

this is total code :

```
@interface NBViewController () <UIWebViewDelegate,UIScrollViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *imageDownloadsInProgress;
@end


@implementation NBViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.imageDownloadsInProgress = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    CGFloat xOffset = 0;
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        xOffset = 224;
    }

    pullRightView = [[PullableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 200, 300)];
    pullRightView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    pullRightView.openedCenter = CGPointMake(100, 200);
    pullRightView.closedCenter = CGPointMake(-70, 200);
    pullRightView.center = pullRightView.closedCenter;
    pullRightView.animate = NO;

    pullRightView.handleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    pullRightView.handleView.frame = CGRectMake(170, 0, 30, 300);

    [self.view addSubview:pullRightView];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 30)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.text = @"User name";
    label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
    label.center = CGPointMake(185, 80);

    [pullRightView addSubview:label];

    NSString *s = self.Bodys;
    s =  [@"<html dir=\"rtl\">" stringByAppendingString:s];
    s = [s stringByAppendingString:@"</html>"];
    UIWebView *bweb = (UIWebView *)[self.view viewWithTag:3];
    UIImageView *uimg = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:20];
    UILabel *title = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:2];

    uimg.image = self.NBimage;
    [title setText:self.Titles];
    bweb.delegate = self;
    [bweb loadHTMLString:s baseURL:nil];
    bweb.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    bweb.scrollView.bounces = NO;
}
-(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews{
     UIScrollView *sv = (UIScrollView *)[self.view viewWithTag:30];
    if((self.cellhieghtforwebview != nil)){
        NSLog(@"not null enter %d" , (int)*(self.cellhieghtforwebview));
        if((int)*(self.cellhieghtforwebview) > 0){
        NSLog(@"above zero enter %d" , (int)*(self.cellhieghtforwebview));

     sv.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0,(int)*(self.cellhieghtforwebview));
            }
    }else{
        NSLog(@"aaaa %d" ,  1200);
    sv.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0,1200);
    }
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    NSArray *allDownloads = [self.imageDownloadsInProgress allValues];
    [allDownloads makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(cancelDownload)];
    [self.imageDownloadsInProgress removeAllObjects];
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)bweb
{
    CGRect frame = bweb.frame;

    frame.size.height = 5.0f;

    bweb.frame = frame;
}
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)bweb{
    NSLog(@"finish loading");
    CGSize mWebViewTextSize = [bweb sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f)]; 
    CGRect mWebViewFrame = bweb.frame;
    mWebViewFrame.size.height = mWebViewTextSize.height;
    self.cellhieghtforwebview = &(mWebViewFrame.size.height);
    bweb.frame = mWebViewFrame;
    NSLog(@"%f",*self.cellhieghtforwebview);
    bweb.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    bweb.scrollView.bounces = NO;
    UIScrollView *sv = (UIScrollView *)[self.view viewWithTag:30];
    sv.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, *(self.cellhieghtforwebview));
    [self viewDidLayoutSubviews];
}

-(void)bweb:(UIWebView *)bweb didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
   NSLog(@"error loading");
}

@end
```

screenshot of storyboard :

[image]

Comment: Do you have other view upon UIScrollView or you have only the UIWebView upon UIScrollView?

Comment: yes i have two other view (uiimageview , label) in it too. both of them are inside uiscrollview too.

Comment: are you adding the imageview and label bellow or above the webview? Can you make a image and attach it so that I can understand what your view should look like?

Comment: sure ive added screenshot of storyboard

Answer (score 1):

If you are using autolayout then the resizing of UIScrollview height will not be effective. Turn autolayout off from IB and then try to set the height of UIScrollView.

[image]

Uncheck the option and then try to resize the scrollview. Hope this helps. :)

**EDIT:**
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825189/auto-layout-uiscrollview-with-subviews-with-dynamic-heights/16868085#16868085) question this may help.

Comment: thanks for answer problem is i want use autolayout feature on.
thats why im using "viewDidLayoutSubviews".