# Set auto layout dynamically to scroll view in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, scrollview

i am creating scroll view dynamically now i want to set auto layout for that 
     i implemented following code to set auto layout but its not working at all.

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
   [super viewDidLoad];
        self.navigationItem.title=@"Insta SMS Collection";
        scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];


    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    NSDictionary *views = @{@"scrollView":scrollView};
    [scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:  
    [scrollView]"
    options:kNilOptions
    metrics:nil
    views:views;
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
    }
```

Comment: why you are adding scrollview two times? and you don't need to set frame while using autolayout.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto layout UIScrollView with subviews with dynamic heights](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825189/auto-layout-uiscrollview-with-subviews-with-dynamic-heights)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add horizontal and vertical autolayout.

```
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
NSDictionary *dictScrollConst = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrlView);
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[scrlView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:dictScrollConst]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scrlView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:dictScrollConst]];
```

Maybe this will help you.