# iOS Scrollview not scrolling all the way?

Tags: ios, view, scrollview

Ive set up a scrollview and its not scrolling all the way to the bottom ive got it set up on my XIB as half the size so it will work but as you can see by the code it should work unless ive done something wrong?

**viewcontroller.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;

}   


@end
```

**viewcontroller.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,910)];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: What is the height of the frame for the `UIScrollView` and are you adjusting it to fit the two different screen sizes?

Comment: does this make it any more clear? It just wont scroll all the way to the bottom and in regards to the height of the frame its smaller on the main screen than it is set up in that viewcontroller.m to make it scroll. https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BOMH3D2CMAARTf0.jpg:large

Comment: I think we could better help you if you post the origin coordinates and frame dimensions of your scroll view. Is the scroll view supposed to take up the entire visible space on screen?

Comment: Make sure your scroll view is positioned correctly. You can use springs and struts or auto layout to keep it bound to the top.

Comment: it is positioned correctly and what are springs and struts in relation to this code stuff

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you're running on an 3.5 inch display in the Simulator, but with 4 inch view controllers. In the Simulator, in the menu bar try clicking Hardware>Device>iPhone (Retina 4-inch).

Also, in your viewDidLoad, [super viewDidLoad] should be the first thing being called.

Comment: just tried loading it up in other simulators and its still not working :( it does the same thing every time it will only scroll a small chunk of the code

Answer (score 0):

Try this (it solved my problem):

```
scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:lastSubView
                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                toItem:scrollView
                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                            multiplier:1.0
                                              constant:0]];
```

REFERENCE: [UIScrollView doesn't use autolayout constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499467/uiscrollview-doesnt-use-autolayout-constraints)