# Efficient strategy to creative a UIView which is the size of device's screen

Tags: ios, uiview, uiwebview

**Context**

I'm creating a `UIView` to act as the "container view" (let's call it `containerView`) for a `UIScrollView`, this `UIScrollView` will then house a `UIWebView`. See this question for more context. [Matching subview's width to it's superview using autolayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341600/matching-subviews-width-to-its-superview-using-autolayout)

**Goal**

Have the `containerView`, when created, be "full screen", i.e. take up the whole screen. I can then tie the `containerView's` size, through auto-layout constraints to the `UIWebView` and make the UIWebView, be full width of the screen.

**Questions**

- What is the best strategy for this? Using `[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];`

Comment: Do you have a controller for your view? If yes, make that the root controller of the window object and the view will be full screen size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can try something like this:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
```