# UIImageView initWithFrame not correct size when using self.view.frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, frame, cgrect

I am having an issue where when I create several UIImageViews programmatically and give them the frame of the main view they end up being half the size. I am building the app in the simulator on a 3.5in retina screen. I checked the frame of the main view and it is (in Landscape) 480pts wide, 320pts high and the origin is at (0,0). It should fill the same part of the screen as the main view (blue in the image below). I'm sure I'm missing something super simple but I just don't see it and searching around for a bit hasn't yielded an answers.

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image: ImageViews as they appear in the simulator]

Comment: Show your relevant code or no one can help you find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First : You need set contentMode for imageView

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

Second : Set imageFrame frame by view bounds

```
imageView.frame = self.view.bounds;
```

Third : You use Auto layout

Comment: I had the content mode set to AspectModeFit. So doing both of these solved the problem. Thanks so much for your quick response!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few thing to consider:

- Are you sure your image/imageView contentMode is set properly?

  imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
- Are you sure you have auto-layout constraints/autoresizing masks are set properly?
- Have you taken care of screen-rotation?

It'd be helpful if you post some code samples. Otherwise, it's very difficult to find exactly where the problem is.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
```

or

```
imageView.frame = self.view.bounds;
```

Also set autoresizing mask either in storyboard or in code
In code:

```
imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | 
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | 
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | 
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | 
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | 
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

[image]

If you are using auto-layout look at this link [Matching subview's width to it's superview using autolayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341600/matching-subviews-width-to-its-superview-using-autolayout)