# Can UIStackView be constrained?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout, uistackview

I have a `UIScrollView` that fills all the window and that contains a vertical `UIStackView` where I want to add `UILabels` that fill all available width.

The `UIStackView` is pinned to all the edges of `UIScrollView`, and I expect it to fill all the `UIScrollView`. But it seems that it completely ignores all the constriants and it only sizes to fit it's childs. Why that behaviour?

To illustrate that if I add labels that way:

```
    scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[stackView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.alignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["stackView": stackView]))
    scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[stackView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.alignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["stackView": stackView]))

    for _ in 1 ... 20 {
        let textLabel = UILabel()
        textLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        textLabel.text  = "Hi World xxxx"
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(textLabel)
        textLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.widthAnchor).isActive = true //Doesn't work as expected

    }
```

what I get is this: (the cyan background is the `UIScrollView` and you can see that labels doesn't take all width due to that `UIStackView`  contraints doesn't apply)

[image: Result with stackview contraints]

And only if I change the label contraint to use scrollView it works as desired:

```
textLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

Then the result is as expected:
[image]

Why that behaviour? Someone can explain why the constraints on `UIStackView` doesn't work as I expect?

Complete source code [avaiable at that gist](https://gist.github.com/lujop/3a6af51c8c47e7d65195400bea5c79c8)

Comment: Hi lujop, `alignAllCenterX` has no effect in your code. You can remove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is correct. Its just that you have not specified the width of the content view(the stack view). 
Add this line and thing will work perfectly.

```
scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true;
```

**Note:** Pinning scroll view's leading trailing with content view does, not provide the width to the content view. A separate width constraint is required, other wise the content view will have its width equal to its intrinsic width. 
Links: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18341997/1790683

Comment: Thanks @BangOperator. Do you have more information on why the width constraint is needed? Normally pinning to borders it's enough to determine width, it isn't?

Comment: Yes scrollviews a a bit different. You can google uiscrollview with autolayout. I will paste relevant links soon