# Handling iPhone 3.5inch and IPhone 4inch display (UIScrollView)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm having difficult dealing with the designing a layout that fits both 3.5inch iphone and 5 inch iPhone (Simulators). I had auto layout checked, and all the layouts were perfect. However I now need to use a UIScrollView, and therefore need to uncheck auto-layout to use.

Also when viewing the layout with an iPhone 4 inch display its adds about 60px to the top of the UIScrollView.

Is there a better way to do this (set up scrollview without deselecting auto-layout)? So i can support iPhone 4.

```
//to set up the scrollview
[self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 800)];
```

however it does not scroll until I uncheck the autolayout. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: please put the screenshot of your issue for better understanding.

Comment: `UIScrollView, and therefore need to uncheck auto-layout to use` why is that?

Comment: @ArkadiuszHolko the scroll view wont scroll without unchecking auto -layout for some reason. I could be doing it wrong however.

Comment: @Gman add more code and put screenshot too to understand little bit more....

Comment: @Gman there is no other code, I used the story board to hook up the scrollview and set its height bigger than the view itself ie. 800h.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (it solved my problem):

```
scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:lastSubView
                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                            toItem:scrollView
                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                        multiplier:1.0
                                          constant:0]];
```

REFERENCE: [UIScrollView doesn't use autolayout constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499467/uiscrollview-doesnt-use-autolayout-constraints)

Answer (score 1):

Try autoresize,

```
 self.scrollView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin);
```

Answer (score 0):

`UIScrollView` when using Autolayout is slightly different. You need to do some modifications. You answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499467/uiscrollview-doesnt-use-autolayout-constraints).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I tried implementing what was suggested but I think I got a bit lost, I created a subview and added it do scrollview rather than adding the uiElements to it `[scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:lastSubView                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight                                                        multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];`

Comment: Now are you using Auto layout? Checked Auto-Layout? Did you add `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;` if you are using Auto layout?

Comment: I was using AutoLayout but I was not using `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;`, will this make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to your `UIScrollView frame`. Assign frame to scrollview as per below CGRect.

```
CGRect rect=[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

Hope, this will work for you.

Comment: Could you further explain please?