# UIScrollView with scaled UIImageView using autolayout

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, interface-builder, autolayout

[image: UIScrollView with UIImageView]

Consider a `UIScrollView` with a single subview. The subview is an `UIImageView` with the following size constraints:

- Its height must be equal to the height of the `UIScrollView`.
- Its width must be the width of the image scaled proportionally to the height of the `UIImageView`.

It is expected that the width of the `UIImageView` will be bigger than the width of the UIScrollView, hence the need for scrolling.

The image might be set during `viewDidLoad` (if cached) or asynchronously.

How do you implement the above using autolayout, making as much use as possible of Interface builder?

### What I've done so far

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13548039/143378) I configured my nib like this:

- The `UIScrollView` is pinned to the edges of its superview.
- The `UIImageView` is pinned to the edges of the `UIScrollView`.
- The `UIImageView` has a placeholder intrinsic size (to avoid the *Scrollable Content Size Ambiguity* error)

As expected, the result is that the `UIImageView` is sized to the size of the `UIImage`, and the `UIScrollView` scrolls horizontally and vertically (as the image is bigger than the `UIScrollView`).

Then I tried various things which didn't work:

- After loading the image manually set the frame of `UIImageView`.
- Add a constraint for the width of the UIImageView and modify its value after the image has been loaded. This makes the image even bigger (?!).
- Set `zoomScale` after the image is loaded. Has no visible effect.

### Without autolayout

The following code does exactly as I want, albeit without autolayout or interface builder.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    {
        UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
        self.scrollView = scrollView;
    }

    {
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
        self.scrollView.contentSize = imageView.frame.size;
        self.imageView = imageView;
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self layoutStripImageView];
}

- (void)layoutStripImageView
{ // Also called when the image finishes loading
    UIImage *image = self.imageView.image;
    if (! image) return;

    const CGSize imageSize = image.size;
    const CGFloat vh = self.scrollView.frame.size.height;
    const CGFloat scale = vh / imageSize.height;
    const CGFloat vw = imageSize.width * scale;

    CGSize imageViewSize = CGSizeMake(vw, vh);
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageViewSize.width, imageViewSize.height);
    self.scrollView.contentSize = imageViewSize;
}
```

I'm trying really hard to move to autolayout but it's not being easy.

Answer (score 11):

Under the autolayout regime, ideally the UIScrollView **contentSize** is solely determined by the constraints and not set explicitly in code.

So in your case:

- *Create constraints to pin the subview to the `UIScrollView`.* The constraints have to ensure the margin between the subview and the scroll view are 0. I see that you have already tried this.
- *Create a height and a width constraint for your subview.* Otherwise, the intrinsic size of the `UIImageView` determines its height and width. At design time, this size is only a placeholder to keep Interface Builder happy. At run time, it will be set to the actual image size, but this is not what you want.
- *During `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, update the constraints to be actual content size.* You can either do this directly by changing the `constant` property of the height and width constraint, or calling `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` and overriding `updateConstraints` to do the same.

This ensures that the system can derive `contentSize` solely from constraints.

I've done the above and it works reliably on iOS 6 and 7 with a `UIScrollView` and a custom subview, so it should work for `UIImageView` too. In particular if you don't pin the subview to the scroll view, zooming will be jittery in iOS 6.

You may also try creating height and width constraints that directly reference a multiple of the height and width of the scroll view, but I haven't tried this other approach.

Comment: Thank you so much! Setting height and width constraints does it for me.

Answer (score 2):

**`translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`** is only required when you instantiate the view in the code. If you instantiate it in the IB it's disabled by default

In my opinion the `UIImageView` should fill the `ScrollView`. Later I'd try setting the zoom of the `scrollview` to the value that suits you well so the image can only be panned in one direction

Comment: I tried. `zoomScale` appears to have no effect on the `UIScrollView`.

Comment: Edited the question to remove `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a full width UIImageView the had a defined height constraint that causing the problem.

I set another constraint on the UIImageView for the width that matched the width of the UIScrollView as it is in interface builder then added an outlet to the UIViewController:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *imageViewWidthConstraint;
```

then on viewDidLayoutSubviews I updated the constraint:

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    self.imageViewWidthConstraint.constant = CGRectGetWidth(self.scrollView.frame);
}
```

This seemed to do the trick.