# How To Add A UILabel To A UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am trying to add labels to my scroll view. I have successfully made the scrollview for both iPhone and iPad size using storyboards on Xcode 5 for iOS 7, but when I add a label it no longer scrolls.

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Edit:

ViewController.h:

```
IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrolling;
IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollingIpad;
```

ViewConroller.m

```
  [scrolling setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scrollingIpad setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scrolling setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 600)];
    [scrollingIpad setContentSize:CGSizeMake(768, 2000)];
```

Comment: How you initialize and add this label to the scrollView? And why do you have two scrollViews? You can use one `IBOutlet` to `UIScrollView` and use different `contentSize` for iPhone and iPad.

Comment: is `Autolayout` enabled for the `superView`? in which case, disable it & see if you are still facing the same issue

Comment: check my updated answer below :D

Comment: My UILabel is being added by click and drag inside of the storyboard. I will just try a table view.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the method in the UIScrollView class, named `setContentSize`

Should fix your issue, if not, maybe you should update your question with codes and more info.
Thanks.

UPDATE:

I don't see why this isn't working. However, the best way to let the controller manages itself is to use a UITableView, then add a view to it, and a label in that view.

This way, automatically, the table view will detect the size of its content then enable the scrolling for that area.

Not the best way, but a way that I have been doing and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

1. Disable `Autolayout` on the `superView`

   ### or...
2. Keep `Autolayout` on the `superView` but manage your constraints appropriately

also see:
[UIScrollView doesn't use autolayout constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499467/uiscrollview-doesnt-use-autolayout-constraints)