# Image doesn't scroll with text

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uitextview

Sorry for my english firstly.
I have an image and a text which are both must be scrolled.But they don't.
So here i have a piece of my code,where i've trying to do what i need to:

```
self.newsBody.text = [self bodyWithoutTags:self.newsContent];
NSData *imgData = [ServerRequest getImgFromServer:self.newsImage];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 225);
self.newsImageView.image = img;
self.newsImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
self.newsImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;;
self.newsImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 204);


self.newsBody.frame = CGRectMake(0, 202, 320, 225);


self.newsBody.clipsToBounds = YES;
self.newsBody.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

self.newsBody.scrollEnabled = NO;
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.newsImageView];
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.newsBody];
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: Are you using Autolayout for the ScrollView?

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1501218/chris13) yes,i use that

Comment: I'm not what's really the problem - I usually don't use Autolayout - but maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499467/uiscrollview-doesnt-use-autolayout-constraints/13548039#13548039) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your real content size ...

```
self.newsImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 204);
self.newsBody.frame = CGRectMake(0, 202, 320, 225);
```

... is 320 x ( 202 + 225 ), which is 320 x 427. But you do set scroll view's content size to ...

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 225);
```

... which is actually wrong. Scrolling is done when you do set correct content size and content size is bigger than scroll view itself. Otherwise it's not scrolling, no need to scroll if your content is smaller than scroll view itself.