# Autolayout constraint that uses UIScrollview contentSize

Tags: xcode, ios7, uiscrollview, autolayout, xcode6

I have a `UIView` inside a `UIScrollView`.  I can easily pin the height to the `UIScrollView`'s frame height.

How do I add a constraint that pins to the UIScrollView's `contentSize` instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer "Adding constraints programatically" is correct but it was a little light on detail for me to accept it as the full answer.

Here's how I did it!

1. Remove all storyboard constraints on the WebView
2. Add a Placeholder constraint in storyboard for the constraint that you will add with code.  This step is very important (and easily missed) or you will get an error about conflicting constraints.[image: Placeholder constraint]
3. Add code to webviewDidFinishLoad delegate method

--Code--

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width, _headerImageView.frame.size.height + webView.scrollView.contentSize.height);



    _webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{@"myWebView":_webView};

    NSString *constraintsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:[myWebView(%i)]", (int)_scrollView.contentSize.height];


    NSArray *constraint_H = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:constraintsString options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];

    [_webView addConstraints:constraint_H];


}
```

Answer (score 2):

UIScrollView have dynamic constraints, left, top, width and height are generated at runtime. If you put a UIView inside a UIScrollview and Pin fixed constraints in Interface Builder it will generate an error because the parameters are relative to Superview/Container View.

[image]

You can try some workarounds:

1- Add UIView constraints Programmatically

http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout-programmatically/

2- Manually resize your view bounds in initWithFrame function inside a UIView Subclass

Please give me any feedback about your progress.

Comment: any progress? @sayguh