# UIScrollView does not Scroll completely

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a ViewController. In it I put ScrollView with the View(contentView). Later I drag from contentView to View and set Equal Height. Now it scrolls, but not fully.

[image]

[image]

> As you see there are it has continue below the textView, but it
>   doesn't scrolls. How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you set the contentsize of scrollview?

Comment: @Leo no. I want to do it automatically, but do not know how to do it. Can you help me?

Comment: Since he is using Auto Layout it doesn't need to set contentSize. You set contentView height as equal to view height, why should it scroll ?

Comment: @Poql is it wrong way?

Comment: @Poql wether or not you use auto layout, you HAVE TO set the contentSize which by default is (0, 0)

Comment: Wrong. http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch20.html

Comment: @Nico I did try the answer of Sohil below and it does not help me, too

Comment: @Poql yes you're right, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

UIScrollView is able to automatically calculate it's content height and width, but you need to help it with this.
To do so you need to:

1. Bound `contentView` (in your case) to all sides of superview (which is `Scroll View`).
2. Let `contentView` to calculate it's sizes. Here is a small mistake in your approach. You've set height of the `contentView` equal to `View`'s height. So basically `Scroll View`'s contentSize.height is the same as `View`'s height. Which is not really what you want with dynamic content.

Usually you want to set width of the `contentView` equal to `View`'s width and do not set `contentView`'s height. Instead you want to bind subviews of `contentView` to their superview in such a way that their superview (`contentView`) will calculate it's height automatically.

In your case I would bind:

- `pizza.jpg` to left-top-right of superview (height of `pizza.jpg` will be set from intrinsic image size);
- `SAMPLE TITLE` label - left-right to superview; top to `pizza.jpg` image;
- `Text View` - left-bottom-right to superview; top to `SAMPLE TITLE` label; set a fixed height.

In this case `contentView` will define needed height by itself. `Scroll View` will set it's contentSize accordingly.
And your screen will be able to scroll vertically (it should be) ;)

Comment: The correct answer after researching for hours. You saved my day. The key point is, setting the bottom constraint of the most bottom to the bottom of the content view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the contentsize of the scrollview. Use the below code to do that:

```
func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.contentView.frame.size.height);

}
```

Comment: it doesn't help me. Must I delete my constraint - Equal Height or not? I delete it and it does not scroll at all

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade For contentView, you just need to set constraint perspective to scrollview. Top = Bottom = Left = Right = 0

Answer (score 0):

To use `Autolayout` with `UIScrollView` is tricky.

In your code you have to update height constraint for your **contentView** by calculating height of `subviews` of `contentView` and that will automatically update the `contentSize` for your `ScrollView` and you can scroll through all subviews.

For more info to use **Autolayout+UIScrollView** your can read [this](http://natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/index.html) (thanks to [this Matt's answer first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499467/uiscrollview-doesnt-use-autolayout-constraints/13548039#13548039)), UIScrollView acts differently with AutoLayout than the other views.

Subviews of a scrollView set their constraints from the contentView of the scrollView and not the scrollview directly. This allows the content to scroll.

So :

1. Add a UIView to your scrollView, this will represent the contentView of your scrollView. Add constraints to top, bottom, trailing, leading from the view to its superView
2. Interface Builder complains. Here you see the different between a basic view and a scrollView. The reason is a contentView has to be fill to know its size. So add a equal width from the contentView to the scrollView
3. The contentView knows now its width but not its height. So add your labels and your UIImage as subviews of the contentView. Add constraints from bottom to the top. Don't miss to add a height constraint to the UIImageView.

It should look like this :

[image]

Hope this helps

Read [this (from Matt once again)](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch20.html) for further informations