# UIScrollView wrong offset with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a fairly simple view configuration:

A `UIViewController`, with a child `UIScrollView` and a `UIImageView` in this `UIScrollView`.
I set the `UIImageView` with a height sufficient to break out of the visible area (ie. higher to `1024pt`), and set the `Bottom space to superview` constraint of my `UIImageView` to a fixed positive value (`20` for example).

[image: project layout]

The whole setup works as expected, the image scrolls nicely in its parent.
Except when the view is scrolled (the effect is more visible if you scrolled to the bottom of the view), then disappear, and appear again (you switched to another view and came back) the scrolling value is restored, but the content of the scroll view is moved to the outside top part of its parent view.

This is not simple to explain, I'll try to draw it:
[image: visual representation of previous paragraph]

If you want to test/view the source (or the storyboard, I did not edit a single line of code). I put a little demo on my github: https://github.com/guillaume-algis/iOSAutoLayoutScrollView

I did read the [iOS 6 changelog](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/index.html) and the explanation on this particular topic, and think this is the correct implementation of the second option (pure auto layout), but in this case why is the `UIScrollView` behaving so erratically ? Am I missing something ?

**EDIT**: This is the exact same issue as [#12580434 uiscrollview-autolayout-issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580434/uiscrollview-autolayout-issue). The answers are just workarounds, as anyone found a proper way to fix this or is this a iOS bug ?

**EDIT 2**: I found another workaround, which keep the scroll position in the same state the user left it (this is an improvement over [12580434](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580434/uiscrollview-autolayout-issue)'s accepted answer):

```
@interface GAViewController ()

@property CGPoint tempContentOffset;

@end


@implementation GAViewController

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.tempContentOffset = self.mainScrollView.contentOffset;
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.scrollView.contentOffset = self.tempContentOffset;
}
```

This basically save the offset in `viewWillAppear`, reset it to the origin, and then restore the value in `viewDidAppear`. The problem seems to occur between these two calls, but I can't find its origin.

Comment: Thanks for your second edit, it seems to the best work around I can find. The solution of Mark Kryzhanouski does not work in my setup. The only problem with EDIT 2 is that, when navigating back, you can see scrollview offset snap back to its original position.

Comment: In my case I was able to work around the issue by adding all contraints to the top level view, rather than the scroll view.

Comment: Brilliant explanation of this issue. I am running into it now and I can't believe it hasn't been fixed.

Comment: You should really write your EDIT 2 into an answer so that we can upvote it.

Comment: @Pang Upvote the question ;). I'm not adding it as an answer because it's just a workaround. And afaik it was fixed in iOS 7.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yeah, something strange happened with UIScrollView in pure autolayout environment. Re-reading the [iOS SDK 6.0 release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/index.html) for the twentieth time I found that:

> Note that you can make a subview of the scroll view appear to float (not scroll) over the other scrolling content by creating constraints between the view and a view outside the scroll view’s subtree, such as the scroll view’s superview.

### Solution

**Connect your subview to the outer view. In another words, to the view in which scrollview is embedded.**

As IB does not allow us set up constraints between the imageView and a view outside the scroll view’s subtree, such as the scroll view’s superview then I've done it in code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self.view removeConstraints:[self.view constraints]];
    [self.scrollView removeConstraints:[self.scrollView constraints]];
    [self.imageView removeConstraints:[self.imageView constraints]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[_scrollView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_scrollView)]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_scrollView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_scrollView)]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[_imageView(700)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_imageView)]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_imageView(1500)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_imageView)]];
}
```

And vau! It works!

Comment: Oh. It works. But why ? It seems to me that it's a sort of blending of the two options Apple provides... And to me, the info you quoted explains how to make a view with a sort of "CSS absolute positioning", which is not supposed to scroll at all.

Comment: I can't explain it too. Seems this is a sort of UIScrollView bug. Hope Apple will change this in future.

Comment: Oh well, strange as it seems you're saying "the UIImageView should always stick to the left side of it's parent view" and this constraint is being held by the controller's view. You're not really saying that the UIImageView should always stick to the left side of the controller's view.

Comment: What does `[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[_imageView(700)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_imageView)]];`  mean exactly? Does `|` here mean its superview (i.e. the scroll view) or does it refer to self.view?

Comment: It means second option (self.view). It is view in which scrollview is embedded.

Comment: I still cannot understand the solution, however I notice that when the navigationController pops back to the scrollView's NC, there will be a breaking constraint error. While I cannot encounter the bug in iOS 7 anymore, I still need those mystery codes for iOS 6 compatibility.... :/

Answer (score 10):

The edit didn't work for me. But this worked:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
     [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

     self.tempContentOffset = self.scrollView.contentOffset;
     self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
     [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
     self.scrollView.contentOffset = self.tempContentOffset;
}
```

Comment: Ditto.  Man, you know you have problems when you have to hook into `-viewDidLayoutSubviews`...

Answer (score 5):

For me I went to the IB clicked my view controller that contains the scroll view. Then I went to Attribute Inspector -> View Controller -> Extend Edges -> Uncheck "Under Top Bars" and "Under Bottom Bars".

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution found, Just put

```
[self setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:NO];
```

in your ViewControllers viewDidLoad method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    [self setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using a UIScrollView in a UIViewController with a top extra space that was not visible in Storyboard. The solution for me was to uncheck the "Adjust Scroll View Insets" on the ViewController storyboard properties : see answer [Extra Space (inset) in Scroll View at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19252852/extra-space-inset-in-scroll-view-at-run-time/19254901#19254901)

Comment: Please read the question and answers carefully. This is not the same problem. This was a bug in iOS 6, before iOS 7 was even announced.

Comment: Issue he is describing is still present in iOS 8, it wasn't fixed or it was reintroduced again (if it's indeed bug and not a feature, you never know with Apple). While it's not really related to the question, it helped me to solve my problem, so thanks for that :)

Answer (score -2):

Add a global property contentOffset and save the current contentOffset in viewDidDisappear.
Once you return the method viewDidLayoutSubviews will be called and you can set your original contentOffset.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:self.contentOffset animated:FALSE];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    self.contentOffset = self.scrollView.contentOffset;
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:FALSE];
}
```

Comment: 1. This question was already solved nearly a year ago. 2. This is bad, because `viewDidLayoutSubviews` will probably be called again later during the controller lifecycle and this will reset the contentOffset again (which is not wanted). 3. Use `NO` instead of `FALSE` in Objective-C. 4. `CGPointMake(0,0)` => `CGPointZero`.

Answer (score -3):

Looks like the problem solved with the `dispatch_async` during the `viewWillAppear:`

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    CGPoint originalContentOffset = self.scrollView.contentOffset;
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.scrollView.contentOffset = originalContentOffset;
    });
}
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It actually fixed the bug for me, and it works without flickering, and no need to recreate view constraints in code.

Comment: I don't know why this is downvoted. I got the similar issue, then need call this self.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero and then call self.contentInset = insets; again in main queue. All value I logged are correct but the UI still wrong. Thank Chebur.