# Multiline UILabel with UIScrollview using autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

I read many post of `contentview` in `scrollview`,but the problem is slightly different.check out the image

[image]
  and i have following hierarchy

[image]

Here the `label` is `multiline label` and its fill up with too many content size.
so, the problem is
   1. according to the lines of the `label`, height of `label` changes and
2. accoring to height of `label`, `contentview` height changes.
so, that it scrolls. and i want this things to be done with `autolayout`.
And one thing i want to mention is , i'm using ios `8.1` and xcode `6.1`

Answer (score 0):

The thing that you can use for your UILabel is -> Select your Label and go to **Attributes Inspector** and find **Autoshrink** set it as **Minimum font size** then you may describe your minimum font size.

For addition to your view, you may want to use constraints between your label and content view. So I recommend to use this documentation [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html). And if the documentation is too long to read you may read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15350131/4175906).

Answer (score 0):

You should add constraint to content-view as leading, trailing, top, bottom & equal width & equal height with scrollView. For imageView add constraint as leading, trailing, top & height. For the Label  add constraint as leading, trailing, top & bottom, also check that you are setting no of lines to be zero. & For read more button add constraints as height, width, centre horizontally in container & bottom. Don't forget to add bottom constraint to button otherwise your scroll view does not understand its content size & you will get warning as ambiguous content size to scroll view.