# Tableheader view autolayout issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, autolayout

I'm loading a custom UIView's XIB file as a header view of a uitableview inside a view controller.

The file owner for the xib file is the viewcontroller. I have both the viewcontroller's & the uiview's interface declared inside the uiviewcontroller.

**ViewController.h**

```
      @class ZeroStateView;

      @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

      @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet CustomUITableView *tableView;
      @property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *dataArray;
      @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet ZeroStateView *zeroStateView;


      @end


     @interface ZeroStateView : UIView
     @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet AutoLayoutLabel *titleLabel;
     @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *titleIcon;

     - (void)updateView;

     @end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
    - (void)prepareHeaderViewForZeroState{
            ZeroStateView *sizingView = [ZeroStateView new];
            [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ZeroStateView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
            sizingView = self.zeroStateView;
           [sizingView updateView];

           self.tableView.tableHeaderView = sizingView;

           UIView *headerView = self.tableView.tableHeaderView;



           CGFloat height = [headerView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

         CGRect headerFrame = headerView.frame;
         headerFrame.size.height = height;
         headerView.frame = headerFrame;


         self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
     }

    @end

    @implementation ZeroStateView

    -(void)updateView{
      self.titleIcon.alpha = 0.5;

      UIFontDescriptor *titleFontDescriptor = [UIFontDescriptor preferredFontDescriptorWithTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleSubheadline];

      self.titleLabel.text =  @"This is a long text message and its really long. This is a long text message and its really long. This is a long text message and its really long. This is a long text message and its really long. This is a long text message and its really long. This is a long text message and its really long. This is a long text message and its really long. This is a long text message and its really long. ";

     }
```

The AutolayoutLabel class the following method overridden:

```
   - (void)setBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
      [super setBounds:bounds];

      // For multiline label, preferredMaxLayoutWidth always matches the frame width
      if (self.numberOfLines == 0 && bounds.size.width != self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth) {
          self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.bounds.size.width;
          [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
      }
   }
```

The height calculated by the *systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize* returns 0. As a result I get the following view as the table header view:
[image: Header view with height 0]

When I added the actual height as below, the uilabel overflows. I'm expecting the uiview to grow as the label height grows.

```
 headerFrame.size.height = self.sizingView.frame.size.height;
```

[image: TableHeaderView not being resized properly]

Here is the screen capture of that UIViews constraints:

[image: ZeroState view XIB file with constraints]

What do I miss here? Can someone point me out?

**Update**
   I created a sample [project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vkjpoc41u6gdcg4/AutoLayoutTest.zip?dl=0) for you guys to check on whats exactly issue is.

Comment: For what it's worth, it always helps to state  your question in the first sentence.

Comment: You should't call this `ZeroStateView *sizingView = [ZeroStateView new];` if you assign something else to it 2 lines later.

Comment: When do you call `prepareHeaderViewForZeroState ` ?

Comment: its called in the viewwillappear method

Comment: Yes, expecting the view's height to grow

Comment: Ok....just have a same problem...just check this question...if its related to you then i have a solution for you...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29047589/multiline-uilabel-with-uiscrollview-using-autolayout

Comment: Your problem is an easy one with how your constraints are set up. I'll post an answer tonight when I'm on my computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reimplemented what you had so far in a different way. To start, I removed the `UIView` in `ZeroStateView.xib` that the `UIImageView` and `UILabel` were embedded in. The base of the xib is already a `UIView`, so it is unnecessary to add another `UIView` to it.

Next I changed the constraints around. I don't remember exactly what constraints I changed, so I will just list them out here:

1. Constraints for `UIImageView`

   - Align Center X to Superview
   - Width = 60
   - Height = 56
   - Top Space to Superview = 37
   - Bottom Space to `UILabel` = 31
2. Constraints for `UILabel`

   - Left Space to Superview = 15
   - Right Space to Superview = 15
   - Bottom Space to Superview = 45
   - Top Space to `UIImageView` = 31

Onto the code. In `ViewController.h`, the `IBOutlet` wasn't doing anything as far as I could tell, so I changed that property to read `@property (strong, nonatomic) ZeroStateView *zeroStateView;`

Now the important changes: `ViewController.m`. There are two `UITableViewDelegate` methods that will replace `prepareHeaderViewForZeroState`. In `viewDidLoad`, initialize the `zeroStateView` and set the table view's delegate to `self`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //...

    // Load the view
    self.zeroStateView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ZeroStateView" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
    [self.zeroStateView updateView];
    self.zeroStateView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    // Set self for table view delegate for -heightForHeaderInSection: and viewForHeaderInSection:
    self.dataTable.delegate = self;
}
```

Now that we are the table view's delegate, we get two method calls that will allow us to customize the header view and set its height appropriately.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // This will set the header view to the zero state view we made in viewDidLoad
    return self.zeroStateView;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // sizeToFit describes the size that the label can fit itself into.
    // So we are saying that the label can use the width of the view and infinite height.
    CGSize sizeToFit = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT);

    // Then we ask the label to tell us how it can fit in that size.
    // The label will respond with the width of the view and however much height it needs
    // to display its text. This is the magic of how it grows vertically.
    CGSize size = [self.zeroStateView.titleLabel sizeThatFits:sizeToFit];

    // Add the height the label needs to the overall zero state view. This should be changed
    // to the height of the UIImage + the height we just got + the whitespace above and below
    // each of these views. You can handle that part.
    return self.zeroStateView.frame.size.height + size.height;
}
```

I uploaded my changes to Dropbox [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3llcihco9riufh2/AADEZRNu24T8GKHNqHwO7DLYa?dl=0).

Answer (score 1):

Just changing the size of the frame of the tableHeaderView, doesn't change it's size. You have to set it again to the tableView to force a reload.

You have to call this again `self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;` after setting the new frame size.

Comment: but systemLayoutSizeFittingSize returns zero

Comment: Whatever other problems you have, you _must_ set self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView; again or height changes in the header view will have no effect on the table view. Consider it a bug in iOS (I do), but you need to do it.

Answer (score 1):

As you call `prepareHeaderViewForZeroState` method from `viewwillappear`. At that point you layout is not calculate. so force layout to calculate before calling `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` method to calculate height of cell. Here are the code that you need to write before calling `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize`.

```
UIView *header = self.tableView.tableHeaderView;

    [header setNeedsLayout];
    [header layoutIfNeeded];
```

**Edit :**

You just left 1 constraints in `ZeroStateView.xib`. that is `Bottom Space to : Superview`. kindly refer screenshot.

[image]

Output :

[image]

Here you have [Updated code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7kttc3BOG13bUoxVVhibWtIcHc/view?usp=sharing)

Hope this help you.

Comment: I updated my code to add in what u suggested but that didn't do much. I updated the sample project. you can play with it when you can.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you could check if you have a leading,trailing,top and bottom constraints for both the UIImage and the label with reference to the superview.

Edit:
Add the width constraint before getting the systemLayoutSize

```
NSLayoutConstraint *tempWidthConstraint =
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:nil
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                            multiplier:1.0
                              constant:CGRectGetWidth(window.frame)];

widthConstraint.constant = tempWidthConstraint.constant;
[self.contentView addConstraint:tempWidthConstraint];

CGSize fittingSize = [self.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
CGFloat height = fittingSize.height +1;
[self.contentView removeConstraint:tempWidthConstraint];
```

Comment: Also add a leading,trailing,top constraints for the Alert Icon image view.

Comment: i would want the imageview to be centered. If i set a trailing space, the imageview icon disappers from the view

Comment: yeah ok, have you tried adding a width constraint for the view before getting the systemLayoutSize, then just remove the width constraint

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things here that are confusing to me that might be complicating things.

1. Why are you subclassing the label?
2. The constraints don't really make sense.

   - Why does the label have two height constraints, a constant and a ≥ constraint? Remove them both, you don't need either.
   - Also, your vertical space to the bottom of the container is ≥ as well. Why? As it stands, your custom view doesn't have a defined height, which could be why the fitting size returns a height of zero.

Once you resolve those issues, let me know if you have better luck.

Comment: Hi thanks for pointing out the mistakes. I updated my code and that didn't do much. I updated the sample project. you can play with it when you can.