# Segue Causes TableView Misalign

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

For the first screen before push segue, the view is loaded perfectly fine. (Refer to Picture 1).

After push segue to the destination screen (Picture 2) and when I tap on the Back bar button item to previous view, the Table View seems like misalign already. And I've tried to log the frame size, content offset and also the view frame size. All seems working properly.

The push segue is hit calling on

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

table view delegate function.

And I log the table view & view frame size in

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated

mTableView frame {{0, 0}, {375, 487}}
mTableView contentOffset {0, 0}
view frame {{0, 0}, {375, 667}}
```

iOS Version - 8.1
Device - iPhone 6

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

[image: Picture 3]

Answer (score 0):

Added

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

to solve the problem.

Refering to [UIScrollView's origin changes after popping back to the UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404682/uiscrollviews-origin-changes-after-popping-back-to-the-uiviewcontroller)