# UIScrollView does not restore properly

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, viewdidappear

I have a Scrollview, it's properties are set in viewDidAppear.
Now when I get to the Scrollview first time there isn't any problem. However I have buttons that are assigned to UINavigationController. So when I press into one of them UINavigationController opens up, when I close the navigation controller, ScrollView does not restore properly. It basically aligns the centre of the screen as previously pressed button location. So if I try to scroll up it does not.

I have tried using this in my viewDidAppear:

```
scrollView.center = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, scrollView.contentOffset.y);
```

Which did not quite work. How can I solve this? I am using iOS6.1

Comment: Can you post some pictures to illustrate what you mean?  I'm having a hard time visualizing the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIScrollview Autolayout Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580434/uiscrollview-autolayout-issue)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually I found the answer here:

[UIScrollview Autolayout Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580434/uiscrollview-autolayout-issue)

The exact code that I used is:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    //save the current offset
    previousPoint = scrollView.contentOffset;
    //set current view to the beginning point
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    //retrieve the previous offset
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = previousPoint;
}
```

`previousPoint` is nothing but a CGPoint variable declared on the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem before too. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17569514/1367622) shows how to overcome this issue.

Basically, you need to set the scrollview's `contentOffset` appropriately in `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidDisappear:`.

**EDIT:** Here's another related question that you might find useful, [UIScrollview Autolayout Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580434/uiscrollview-autolayout-issue).

Comment: @SarpKaya `recentContentOffest` is a variable that saves the `contentOffset` of your scrollview when you leave the view (in your case, when you tap the button the UINavigationController opens up). The answer that I linked to saves this `contentOffset` when the scrollview disappears so it can be reset when the scrollview appears again.