# UIScrollView contentOffset change after another view pushed

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I have a `UIViewController` in Interface Builder, and I add a `UIScrollView` to the `UIView`. It has a `contentOffset` property equal to 0.0, but when I scroll the `UIScrollView` to the very bottom and push another view the `contentOffset` changes.

`NSLog` gives me the following values:

```
//View just loaded
2013-09-09 16:19:27.455 my_app[24588:907] Scroll View content offset is 0.000000

//We came back from another view
2013-09-09 16:19:30.957 my_app[24588:907] Scroll View content offset is 108.000000
```

What's the reason of this behaviour? I've just added a `UIScrollView` in IB and did nothing in code at all.

The `contentHeight` of the scrollView is bigger than `self.view.height`. The `frame` of the scrollView stays the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18010459/1367622) to a similar question.

You need to set the scrollview's `contentOffset` appropriately in `viewWillAppear:` and `viewWillDisappear:`.

Also, see this:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17569514/1367622) to the question [UIScrollView's origin changes after popping back to the UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404682/uiscrollviews-origin-changes-after-popping-back-to-the-uiviewcontroller).
- This related question, [UIScrollview Autolayout Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580434/uiscrollview-autolayout-issue).

Comment: Oh gosh, what a horrible bug! Hope Xcode 5 and iOS 7 have it fixed. Thanks for the ultimate answer!

Comment: No problems, I'm hoping it gets fixed soon too :)

Comment: hah, StephSharp @SergeyGrischyov 5 years on and this problem still persists.

Comment: Only this works, I even tried `UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever` which also failed.

Answer (score 13):

For iOS 7/8 `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;` solved the problem.

Comment: Be careful, this is just for iOS7 min

Comment: This was the best fix for me, setting the contentOffset to 0 caused a visible jump.

Comment: Thiis does not fix it for me a and I have to follow the guidelines in the accepted answer and manually update the `contentOffset` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` . Any idea what is going on with that problem - its 2015 !

Comment: automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets was removed in iOS 12ish. Now use...
contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
It solved a similar problem for me that I had struggled with for hours.

Answer (score 4):

When you leave the screen where the scrollview is present and come back, it will add half of the size of the screen on top or left or both. A blank space, something you don't want. And in my case, the paging becomes a mess and doesn't work properly, until I put the scroll in the CGPointZero programatically or by touch, as an user. If you call `NSLog( @"%f", scrollview.contentSize.height );` on `viewDidLayoutSubviews` you'll see that the size has changed.

It happens on the axis which the offset value is not zero. So, to solve it, you should set it to zero `CGPointZero` before it appears.

The `@Steph Sharp` answer solve my problem except if I open a viewcontroller as a popup (`presentViewController`). I tried to compensate the value by adding the bug amount on `viewDidLayoutSubviews` but it bugs the paging.

Short answer, I end up with:

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    scrollView.contentOffset = previousPoint;
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    previousPoint = scrollView.contentOffset;
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
}
```

Now it works when I leave the section or if I open a popup above.

Answer (score 3):

i had a similar problem, after dismissing a viewController, the contentOffset from my tableView was changed to (0, -64).

my solution was a little weird, i tried all the other answers but had no success,
the only thing that fixed my problem was to switch the tableView position in the controls tree of the .xib

it was the first control in the parent View like this:

[image: before]

I moved the tableView right after the ImageView and it worked:

[image: after]

it seems that putting the table view in the first position was causing the trouble, and moving the table view to another position fixed the problem.

P.D. I'm not using autoLayout neither storyboards

hope this can help someone!

Answer (score 2):

Check if the `contentSize` property of your scrollview is `CGSizeZero`. I had a similar problem because the `contentSize` had been not set.

Answer (score 0):

I was using https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding on UITableView.

My solution was to remove class **TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView** from UITableView. It was causing scroll issue on TableViewController with static and dynamic cells.