# UIScrollViews not synchronizing when leaving view and returning

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have an iPad app (XCode 5, ARC, iOS 7 and Storyboards).  I have a UIView that conceptually looks like this:

[image]

Initially, the display looks like this (notice the time on the left hand grid):

[image]

When I switch to another view and return to this view, notice the time now:
[image]

Apparently it's been like this since day one, and I just found it.

**If I "nudge" the  UIScrollView (move it ever so slightly), the left hand grid then shows the correct time.**

Anybody have suggestions of where to look to fix this?

Comment: Looks like it could be this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18730399/1367622

Comment: Steph Sharp:  works like a champ!  and to think it's not fixed in iOS 7... what a mess!  Please re-write your comment as an answer so I can close this... and tell me where to send the pizza!  lol  Thank you so much... SD

Comment: Glad it worked! I'll write it as an answer now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [my answer to a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18730399/1367622).

You need to set the scrollview's `contentOffset` appropriately in `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidDisappear:`.